# Insert Dynamic Value in URL from a Cell in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a URL in a cell (google sheets) which will get some of its values from different cells. I have tried using all different ways I can think of like concatenate, Join, & etc but the problem is that the URL has some curly brackets and " as a requirement and that breaks the formula:

URL Example
[https://katang.io/?t_pid=1&t_extra={"Source":"stackoverflow","Type":"email","Stategy":"banner"}](https://katang.io/?t_pid=1&t_extra=%7B%22Source%22:%22stackoverflow%22,%22Type%22:%22email%22,%22Stategy%22:%22banner%22%7D)

So I need "Source":"**stackoverflow**" to be dynamic

so for example "Source":"**Get Value from Cell A1**"

Any Help or guidance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to note:

1. `""` makes a literal `"` character in a string, so you'll have to double up every one.
2. The & is the concatenation operator in a formula, so you can use that to get values outside of your string.

Therefore, this formula should work:

```
="https://katang.io/?t_pid=1&t_extra={""Source"":"""&A1&""",""Type"":""email"",""Stategy"":""banner""}"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you So much it worked. I really appreciate your help